# get iframe src in a page loaded via jquery $.get?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm loading a page using $.get, that page i load has an `iframe`.
i know the `iframe` id, but for some reason i cant get the src value...

assuming this is my code

```
function loadPage(postid) {

    $.get("/post/" + postid,
    function(data) {

        var p = $(data).find("iframe").attr('src');
        console.log(p)

    })
}
```

i get undefined result...

but the console of data is an Object complete with all the valus i need...i'm not sure if it just a problem of selecting  in the right way

Comment: Can you post in the HTML that you're getting back from your AJAX call?  Your answer may lie there.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
$.get('/someScript', function(result) {
    var frameSource = $('iframe', result).attr('src');
    alert(frameSource);
});
```

Here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jAy5z/). Just make sure you are not violating the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). That's why it's always better to use relative urls when performing AJAX requests (`/somescript`).

Comment: i still get undefined...i updated my code, in fact i don need the host..relative path is good as well

Comment: @camelCase, did you check the working live demo I provided in my answer? Make sure your server responds with proper `Content-Type: text/html` as well.

Comment: yep i did. let's take an example: this is the url http://vogue.tumblr.com/post/4525974917/on-newsstands-nationwide-april-19th, as you see in the source code they have an iframe at the end of the page, if i use the jquery i cannot get the iframe src...

Comment: @camelCase, of course you cannot. That's a different domain than yours (or is your application hosted on http://vogue.tumblr.com?). Did you read about the [same origin policy restriction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) I've linked to in my answer? You cannot send AJAX request to different domains. Only server side scripts hosted on your server.

Comment: that's just an EXAMPLE. let's assume vogue.tumblr.com is mine and i'm calling a relative patch etc.etc.: the point is i cannot get the iframe src.

Comment: @camelCase, I provided you with a working example (look with FireBug you will see the actual AJAX request, response and the correct fetching of the iframe source, also notice the correct Content-Type sent by the server). So up to you to find the differences between your case and the working one.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Please leave a comment when downvoting especially a working solution providing a link to a live **WORKING** example.